# Get count of same value on table

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq

I have this class where the query must result in this list a property.
This property must check on table how many duplicated exists.
This code works, but its very slow. can you help me ?

```cs
var lst = _uow.Repository.GetAll();
var query =
    from p in lst
    select new GetRfqResponse
    {
        ID = p.ID,

        //bad performance
            Count = lst.Where(x => x.Property == p.Property).AsQueryable().Count(),
        //
    };
```

Comment: I don't think `lst.Where(p => p.Property == p.Property)` is right.

Answer (score 3):

Counting in a queryable list can be easily achieved using the `Count()` function:

```
// Find duplicated names
var byName = from s in studentList
             group s by s.StudentName into g
             select new { Name = g.Key, Count = g.Count() };
```

Check [this fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/rhvIJ3) to see it running.

Answer (score 2):

Below is for InMemory

GroupBy should come to help.

```
var propertyGroupedList = list.GroupBy(l=>l.Property);
var query = list.Select(l => new GetRfqResponse{
          Id = l.Id,
          Count = propertyGroupedList.First(g=> g.Key == l.Property).Count()
});
```

Or you can create a dictionary with key as "Property" and value as count, then you will have to loop just once to store the count.
This allows you to get count in constant time

```
Dictionary<string, int> map = new Dictionary<string, int>();
foreach (var item in lst)
{
    if (!map.ContainsKey(lst.Property))
    {
        map.Add(item.Property, 1);
    }
    else
        map[item.Property]++;
}

var z = lst.Select(l => new GetRfqResponse{
    Id = l.ID,
    Count = map[l.Property]
});
```